# How to add new data to field that support multiple field via JSONAPI?

Tags: 8

I am using jsonapi to `PATCH`(update) a content in a content type called "engagement". All the APIs including patch are working fine. However, when I am trying to update a new value to a field with multiple value support, it is replacing existing content with new one added. So, if I already had 2 value and later add one via `PATCH`. It replaces the first with the new one.

1. **Request type:** PATCH
2. **Post Body:**

```
    {   
    "type": "node--engagement",  
    "id": "a799952f-0528-409e-bf9b-707469e35d68",  
    "attributes": {  
        "body": {  
            "format": "full_html"  
        } 
    },  
    "relationships": {  
        "field_attendance": {  
            "data": [  
                {  
                    "type": "paragraph--attendance",  
                    "id": "12qw",  
                    "meta": {  
                        "target_revision_id": "12"  
                     }   
                 }  
            ]   
        }  
    }  
}
```

The field am referring to is field_attendance. I am able to add any no. of data while updating/creating. However not able to update new ones.